# VS Code demote CLOCK_MONOTONIC as undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code (v1.63.2), running on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, in the default setup denotes the CLOCK_MONOTONIC as undefined.

```c
#include <time.h>
...
struct timespec start_time;
(void) clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_time);
```

How should I configure VS code to have CLOCK_MONOTONIC defined?

Answer (score 7):

The fix is to edit the `c_cpp_properties.json` to use `gcc` and define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L`. For example:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Or add it in the settings C/C++ > IntelliSense > Defines

Answer (score 1):

Another option that worked for me is to use a gnu based `cStandard` in `c_cpp_properties.json`

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu99",             /* <------------- GNU based c standard */
            "cppStandard": "c++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```